# How to find additive and multiplicative probability of several dependent events of equal probability

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Say, there are 1000 entities moving randomly in space and each has a same probability of settling or stopping in that space, and in addition, the entities that are still moving modulate their stopping probability depending on their radial distance to already stopped entities and the number of stopped entities within the circumscribed distance.

I expect that the probability that an entity settles should increase with the number of settled entities (or neighbors) within the prescribed fixed radial proximity, as dependent events. That can either happen as an additive or multiplicative increase.

I would like to know how to calculate (theory/formula) the first the additive and second the multiplicative probability of settlement of a moving entity in the prescribed radial vicinity of an already stopped or settled entity as a function of the number of already stopped entities within that radius, if the probability of settlement is the same for each entity (say 0.001).

Comment: If the probability that an entity stops is .001, does that means with probability .999, it never stops? How does time enter into it?

Comment: Also, what is the nature of "space". Is it a subset of $\mathbb{R}$? $\mathbb{R}^2$? $\mathbb{R}^3$? Does it have a shape?

Comment: @quasi space is R2, and no, .999 does not mean an entity never stops. However, once an entity settles, it does not move anymore ... thus once an entity exceeds the fixed stopping probability it stops and does not move again.

Comment: "once an entity exceeds the fixed stopping probability" means what?

Comment: Also, what is the shape of the region in which the entities move? And how do they move?

Comment: @quasi fixed stopping probability is 0.001, equal for all entities, only changes (which is what I am trying to calculate) in additive or multiplicative manner when moving entities are stopping as a function of how many other entities are already stopped within a circular vicinity (not that the shape of the region matters). How do you calculate additive and multiplicative settlement probability in the latter situation assuming that stopping events for moving entities are dependent on the number of stopped entities within a fixed radius? Each entity movement is random in direction and distance.

Comment: Is rime discrete, i.e., stopping only potentially happens at unit time interval boundaries?

Comment: @quasi so the question I am asking is if a 1000 entities are moving in space with a random direction and distance each time step, and each has a baseline stopping probability of 0.001, and at each time step, each entity selects a random number between 0 and 1 and if the selected number exceeds the baseline stopping probability of 0.001 it stops moving. The entities that remain in motion can stop accordingly but have an added stopping criterion: they check how many already settled/stopped entities are within one-unit radius of space from them and adjust their probability - how to calculate this

Comment: @quasi yes stopping only happens at the unit time interval boundaries, time is discrete ...

Comment: Random direction makes sense. Random distance requires further specification. Also, are the velocities constant and all the same? Presumably, entities are represented as point particles. What is the initial configuration? To say $.001$ is the baseline stopping probability means that at every step, a moving entity has probability $.999$ to stop, right?

Comment: @quasi forget random distance, lets consider the base case of unit or 2 unit distance of space covered with each time step for all entities ... any thoughts then?

Comment: Thoughts? I still don't fully understand the process. You left out a lot in your posted question.

Comment: @quasi yes, at each step for each moving entity (point particle; initialized to  a random position configuration in space), the baseline settlement probability is 0.001 so each entity has a 0.999 probability to stop.Yes, the velocities of the entities are constant, the same across board.

Comment: Your statement "the entities that are still moving modulate their stopping probability depending on their radial distance to already stopped entities and the number of stopped entities within the circumscribed distance" is not specified clearly enough.

Comment: My sense is that you will need to simulate the process via a computer program as a prelude to further analysis.

Comment: @quasi I figured, that is why i changed it to a fixed radial distance of 1 unit of space over which settlement probability of moving entities can change (increase) depending on the number of stopped neighbors within this radius. What would be the most basic formula or means of calculating this change in settlement probability as 1) an additive effect, 2) a multiplicative effect

Comment: There's no obvious answer. You need to experiment.

Comment: @quasi, I am really just looking for the most basic of solutions to the most basic of conditions, you can strip it down further of you like ... for instance, wouldn't additive be: P(A) + P(B) - P(A n B), therefore for a 1000 entities randomly moving in space, each with 0.001 settlement probability: (number of stopped entities in each movers vicinity)*(stopping probability > 0.001) - (product of stopping probabilities) ...???

Comment: I still don't understand the intended process well enough to provide any real answers. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.